# How to paste into SourceTree terminal window when using vagrant ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, atlassian-sourcetree

In Sourcetree when you click Terminal and use the `vagrant ssh` command in the window, how to paste text from your clipboard?

These don't work:

- **Ctrl + V**
- **Ctrl+Shift+Ins**
- Right clicking in the window and selecting **Paste**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To paste into it when using Windows, you have to:

- Right click on the top bar
- Select **Edit**
- Select **Paste**

[image: paste into sourcetree vagrant ssh terminal 1]

[image: paste into sourcetree vagrant ssh terminal 2]